# Multiple join criteria with different keys?

Tags: optimization, join, teradata

I am having a hard time formulating this question for a targeted search and so none of the results I am getting seem to describe my exact situation.

I work in healthcare and our tables are enormous, so I need to keep my joins as efficient as possible as I am often joining across databases and with 5-10 tables. Our tables will often have multiple patient identifiers that are unique to the patient/encounter. So here is my question:

Should I join on as many identifiers as I can, or should I join on as few as I can that nets me the desired result? This is in Teradata and Patient_Encounter_Id is unique to a given patient encounter, therefore it is more granular than Patient_Id, with Facility_Id being the least granular item.

Version: Teradata 16.20.32.26

Example:

```
Select *
From tableA A
Join tableB B
  On A.Patient_Encounter_Id = B.Patient_Encounter_Id

VERSUS 

Select *
From tableA A
Join tableB B
  On A.Patient_Encounter_Id = B.Patient_Encounter_Id
  AND A.Patient_Id = B.Patient_Id
  AND A.Facility_Id = B.Facility_Id
```

I tested one versus the other on a single big query:
With extra join criteria the query took 4:43
Using the minimum join criteria the query took 7:36

However the load on our systems is highly variable so I am not sure if this is generalizable and I cant really justify running 50 queries like this to test it. Thanks!

Comment: Please consider reading about [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Hi @mustaccio, thanks for the link. I read through it, but I guess I am asking in a more general sense. I am not trying to optimize a specific query, but learn more general optimization rules that I am having a hard time finding. The DB version is "Teradata 16.20.32.26", which I will add to the question.

Comment: You should join on the logical PK/FK. What's the Primay Index of both tables? Check SHOW TABLE.